# Dropdown menu using angular

Tags: angular

```
import { Directive, HostListener, HostBinding } from "@angular/core";
```

I am the beginner in angular. I am making the website in angular through the tutorial of udemy. I want to make the drop-down button. Both codes are correct. but when I click the drop-down button then the dropdown menu didn't open

```
`@Directive({
selector: '[appdropdown]'
})
export class DropdownDirective  {
@HostBinding('class.Open') isOpen = false; 
@HostListener('click') toggleOpen () {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
}
}`
```

The HTML code and the ts code will be correct but it can not function

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav justify-content-end"> 
    <li class=" nav-item  dropdown" appdropdown>
    <a href="#" class=" nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button">Manage <span 
    class="caret"></span> </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
    <a href="#"> Save Data</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#">Fetch Data</a>
    </li>
    </ul>  
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, please explain your question

Comment: @RashmiKumari i will edit the post kindly check it and give me answer
thanks

Comment: is `Open` class appended to host on click?

Answer (score 1):

You need to import your `DropdownDirective` in your declarations in `app.module`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like invalid CSS. You are not provided any but I have copy-pasted your example into this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gipnfg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

I have added following style

```
li:not(.Open) .dropdown-menu{
  display: none;
}
```

obviously it will not do the "dropdown" effect, but demonstrates that overall technique is working

Answer (score 0):

```
'@Directive({
  selector: '[appToggleDirective]',
})
export class ToggleDirectiveDirective {
  constructor(private _el: ElementRef, private rendered: Renderer2) {}

  @HostBinding('class.show') isOpen = false;

  @HostListener('click') toggleOpen() {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
    let part = this._el.nativeElement.querySelector('.dropdown-menu');
    if (this.isOpen) {
      this.rendered.addClass(part, 'show');
    } else {
      this.rendered.removeClass(part, 'show');
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.